# Chip Button not showing when creating conditional inside render method

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to render a specific chip button based on if it was clicked or not. For that I have set a variable on the component state that holds all button proprieties. However, my if statements inside the render method is not showing the buttons. However, when I place it outside the if statement, it works.

Each element of column state variable, is a chip button state

To try to make it work I used this code on render():

```
 {
    this.state.columns.find(item => {
       if (item.id === '1'){
         return item.show === true ? (
              <Grid item className={classes.chipWrapper}>
               <Chip
               label='Chip 1'
               color="secondary"
               deleteIcon={<DoneIcon />} 
               id='1'
               onClick={this.handleChip}
               />
             </Grid>
              ) : (
             <Grid item className={classes.chipWrapper}>
               <Chip
               label='Chip 1'
               color="secondary"
               deleteIcon={<DoneIcon />} 
               id='1'
               onClick={this.handleChip}
               />
             </Grid>
         )
       }
    })
  }
```

This is what I have on the rest of the code:

```
class ChipFilter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    anchorEl: null,
    columns: [
      {id: "1", show: false}
    ]
 };

//simply change the property "show" of the column chosen
handleChip = (e) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      columns: prevState.columns.map(
      obj => (obj._id === e.currentTarget.id ? Object.assign(obj, { show: true }) : obj)
    )
   }));
}
```

I expected the chip button to show on the screen regardless of the show property, however with different design styles applied by material ui. If show was **true** the chip button would show differently than if it was **false**. Right now it doesn't not show the chip button what so ever.

Comment: Why do you pass the exact same/identical Grid/Chip to both ternary options?
also why is the state variable property name different in setState - obj._id. Why the underscore?

Comment: that's a good question. It doesn't work using obj.id. I pass the identical grid just for the sake of testing if something appears on screen.

Comment: What do you get when you add the following debug
    this.state.columns.find(item => {

       console.log(item.id, typeof item.id)

       if (item.id === '1'){....

Comment: string. It actually enters the right condition, it just doesnt return the visible component

Comment: Dont you also need another return before this.state.columns.find(item => {
...
return  this.state.columns.find(item => {

Comment: Added answer based on the above comments.

Comment: No. didnt' work "threw Expression Expected"

Comment: Ah ..how did i not see this. The way you are using find in the render is incorrect.
Find just returns the item that meets a condition. Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using find in the render is incorrect.
Find just returns the item that meets a condition.

e.g

```
 var found = items.find(function(item) {
   return item > 10;
 })
```

Use map instead

```
 this.state.columns.map(item => {
   if (item.id === '1'){
     return (<div> Inside </div>)
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole

```
 <Grid item className={classes.chipWrapper}>
               <Chip
               label='Chip 1'
               color="secondary"
               deleteIcon={<DoneIcon />} 
               id='1'
               onClick={this.handleChip}
               />
 </Grid>
```

is passed as third subject of a ternary operator on condition

```
item.show === true
```

so `<Chip />` visibility is currently affected by *show* property.

Comment: but the show property doesn't apply to the Chip. it is supposed to show the Chip regardless of the show property. the show property refers to the table columns I want to show/hide. The chip will just show if the column is shown or hidden so its supposed to be visible always